# alert is not working on error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

// Alert is not working on error message ,  I want to insert only few 4 issue after that it should not work.

```js
success: function(msg, String, jqXHR) {
    window.location = 'home.html';


    $("#result").html(msg, String, jqXHR)
    alert("Data Uploaded: ");

    if (msg.success == 'Error') {

      alert("Please close the previous issue");

      window.location = 'home.html';
    }
```

// here (msg.success=='Error') is not working i want to display  this message - "Please close the previous issue" on this .

Comment: You need to check that `msg.success` comming as `Error` or not? if not then condition will never met and alert will not work.  check through `console.log(msg.success);` and see what it prints

Comment: what data is being returned when you make this http request?

Comment: what is happening is it always coming to -   $("#result").html(msg,String,jqXHR).

Comment: String is a saved word in js, do not use it as a variable name

Comment: Why do you have 3 parameters on `.html()`?

Comment: Before using the the object "msg" you should check that it's not null. If "msg" is not null, make sure msg.success is not null or empty.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works for you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#your_form').submit(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     dataString = $("#your_form").serialize();
     $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "post.php",
        dataType:"json",
        data: dataString,
        success: function (response) {
            if(response.status === "success") {
                // do something with response.message or whatever other data on success
                alert("Data Uploaded: ");
                window.location='home.html';
            } else if(response.status === "error") {
                alert("Please close the previous issue");

                 window.location='home.html';
            }
        }
    })
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```